# Clean-up duplicate images from Docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a registry with, for some images, duplicates with different tags. Those different tags have the same digest. The tags also have an increasing version number - e.g:

```
image:478 (digest: foo)
image:477 (digest: foo)
image:476 (digest: foo)
image:475 (digest: bar)
image:474 (digest: baz)
image:473 (digest: baz)
```

While the tool creating those duplicates has since been fixed, I'd like to clean-up the registry (even though the space savings would be minimal as the images are exactly the same) and remove the duplicates. For each digest, I'd like to keep only the oldest tag. As such, the above list would get cleaned up to the following:

```
image:476 (digest: foo)
image:475 (digest: bar)
image:473 (digest: baz)
```

What are my options to do such a clean-up?

Comment: I think if you delete a tag with a specific digest, all the other tags with that digest will dispear as well, since its deleting the underlying image. Maybe pull one of them. Delete the digest and push again.

Comment: I use the GitLab built-in image registry, and removing tags individually from the web interface just unlinks the tag from the image - the image remains in the registry, and the garbage collection needs to run to actually remove any data (which wouldn't do anything in my case as exactly one tag should remain).

Comment: In that case, you can use the http API to fetch a list of tags and do some scripting with the response. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#list-registry-repository-tags

Comment: or even delete in bulk https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#delete-registry-repository-tags-in-bulk

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your registry, you likely won't have the tag delete API. At best, you'll have a manifest delete API, which takes a digest, and deletes all tags pointing to that digest. The workaround that I've done in [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) is to first push a unique empty manifest, and then delete that new manifest. A script to do that would look like:

```bash
repo="registry.example.org/project/name"
last_digest=""
for tag in $(regctl tag ls "${repo}" | sort -r); do
  cur_digest="$(regctl image digest "${repo}:${tag}")"
  if [ "$last_digest" == "$cur_digest" ]; then
    echo "Deleting tag: $tag"
    regctl tag rm "${repo}:${tag}"
  fi
  last_digest="$cur_digest"
done
```

Make sure to test that without the `tag rm` command and verify the correct tags would be deleted.